# Corda Transaction Time get from vault Query

Tags: corda

Is it possible to getting transaction consumed time which can be seen in vault_state through vault query?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can find the time the state was consumed using the `statesMetadata` field of the query result.

**Within a flow:**

```
@Suspendable
override fun call() {
    val results = serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(ContractState::class.java)
    val statesAndMetadata = results.states.zip(results.statesMetadata)
    statesAndMetadata.forEach { (stateAndRef, metadata) ->
        val consumedTime = metadata.consumedTime
    }
}
```

**Within an RPC client:**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    require(args.size == 1) { "Usage: TemplateClient <node address>" }
    val nodeAddress = parse(args[0])
    val client = CordaRPCClient(nodeAddress)

    // Can be amended in the com.template.MainKt file.
    val cordaRPCOps = client.start("user1", "test").proxy

    val results = cordaRPCOps.vaultQueryBy<ContractState>()
    val statesAndMetadata = results.states.zip(results.statesMetadata)
    statesAndMetadata.forEach { (stateAndRef, metadata) ->
        val consumedTime = metadata.consumedTime
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx I was looking to show on UI time when gets consumed... will try same